# POST request from Chrome extension results in 500 error

Tags: javascript, post, google-chrome-extension

I'm making a POST request from a Chrome extension that appears identical to the one that submitting the form manually would do. I've submitted both and compared the body and headers and they seem to be identical.

The POST made via the browser form results in a 302 redirect. The POSTed entry is created and the user ends up on an edit screen for it.

The POST made via the extension results in a 500 error.

I'm filtering many of the headers sent by the extension to match those made by the browser, in case the server is looking for certain things that tip off a request as being non-native.

Hoping to exhaust all options before contacting the devs of the system being POSTed to. Any obvious things that could be happening server-side to block this request?

Here's the POST request made via the browser form:

**Request Headers**

```
Host: myhost.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 901
Referer: https://myhost.com/referer
Cookie: app2=cookieredacted
Connection: keep-alive
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

**Request Body**

```
record[user_name]=aasldkjflasdjf
record[new_password]=ljl;jl;kjklj
record[first_name]=ethan
record[middle_name]
record[last_name]=lastnm
record[name_suffix]
record[gender]=M
record[dob]=07/28/77
record[ssn]=654656546
record[group_number]
record[misc_number]
record[mothers_maiden_name]
record[active]=N
record[active]=Y
record[has_paper_chart]=0
record[notes]
record[address1]=234+htha+st
record[address2]
record[city]=euge
record[county_of_residence]
record[state]=OR
record[zip]=98754
record[country]
record[tel1]=5155555555
record[tel1_status]=4
record[tel2]
record[tel2_status]
record[cell]
record[cell_status]
record[email]=ethan@foo.com
record[preferred_contact]=home_tel
record[house]
record[room]
record[bed]
record[classroom]
```

**Response Headers**

```
Server: nginx/1.6.2
Date: Sun, 09 Jul 2017 01:06:12 GMT
Content-Type: text/plain
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Status: 302 Found
Location: /entry/edit
```

And from the extension:

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.5
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:920
Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Cookie:app2=cookieredacted; gsScrollPos-2545=
Host:myhost.com
Pragma:no-cache
Referer:https://myhost.com/referer
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:1
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.50 Safari/537.36
```

**Request Body**

```
new_password_stub:"FoECbiRN"
record[active]:"Y"
record[address1]:"123 N 5th St"
record[address2]:""
record[bed]:""
record[cell]:""
record[cell_status]:""
record[city]:"Eugene"
record[classroom]:""
record[country]:""
record[county_of_residence]:""
record[dob]:"9/28/91"
record[email]:"ethan@foo.com"
record[first_name]:"Foo"
record[gender]:"M"
record[group_number]:""
record[has_paper_chart]:0
record[house]:""
record[last_name]:"Bar"
record[middle_name]:""
record[misc_number]:""
record[mothers_maiden_name]:""
record[name_suffix]:""
record[new_password]:"FoECbiRN"
record[notes]:""
record[preferred_contact]:"home_tel"
record[room]:""
record[send_notifications]:0
record[ssn]:"222222222"
record[state]:"OR"
record[tel1]:"5155555555"
record[tel1_status]:2
record[tel2]:""
record[tel2_status]:""
record[user_name]:"BarFoo2017"
record[zip]:"97401"
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:keep-alive
Content-Length:5110
Content-Type:text/html; charset=utf-8
Date:Sun, 09 Jul 2017 02:09:33 GMT
Server:nginx/1.6.2
Set-Cookie:mysite_session_id=; max-age=0; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 -0000
Status:500 Internal Server Error
```

Comment: Sort and diff shows that the extension adds `gsScrollPos-2545` cookie, adds `new_password_stub`, uses spaces instead of `+` in `record[address1]` (might not be a problem depending on how you submit the data), adds `record[send_notifications]`. Oh, and only one `record[active]` whereas there were two in the web page.

Comment: `record[send_notofications]` was indeed the problem. Can you give me a quick rundown of how you sorted it? Is there an Atom/Sublime extension I should be aware of?

Comment: @EthanC, While I'm not sure how wOxxOm specifically did the sort/diff(compare), sorting such things prior to comparison is (often) standard operating procedure. There are basic Unix commands [`sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html) and [`diff`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/diff.1.html) that have been around for ~45 years, which are the baseline tools for doing so. There are, however, *many* different ways that you could do it, most of which have improved UI. At a minimum, your text editor of choice should permit you to filter selected text through an external program.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [wOxxOm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45016232/post-request-from-chrome-extension-results-in-500-error?noredirect=1#comment77007293_45016232) for this one -

The extension was posting an extra field `record[send_notifications]` which was causing the 500 error.